# ng-repeat output as variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to loop over an array but change a parent reference each time. I guess my explanation isn't very good so here is my code with comments on what i want to happen

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="number in numbers">  
<!--number = 001 to 054-->
    <div class="col-xs-8 text-center">
        <div data-ng-repeat="item in properties | limitTo: 1">
            <h5 class="text-capitalize">{{item.jobs.001.jobDisplay}}</h5> <!--get 001 to = number-->
            <!--Something like {{item.jobs.{{number}}.jobDisplay}}-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference them via bracket notation:

```
<h5 class="text-capitalize">{{item.jobs[number].jobDisplay}}</h5>
```

Comment: @Zak - Yup. It's just JavaScript at the end of the day, so anything inside the expression is treated as such.